# How to prevent opening of react video modal on click of ESC button?

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I am creating a video page using **react-modal-video** with **gatsby**. Whenever the page loads and I click on the ESC button, the video modal opens automatically. But the video modal should only open on click of a button. I want to stop this transition of the opening of the video modal on the click of the ESC button. I am not getting any idea how to stop this transition. If anyone knows, let me know.

**My Code**

```
const [modal_open, setModalToggle] = useState(false)
const modalToggle = () => setModalToggle(!modal_open)

<ModalVideo channel={props.channel} isOpen={modal_open} videoId={props.video_id} onClose={modalToggle} />

<button onClick={modalToggle}>Show Video</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I trace the **react-modal-video** [source code](https://github.com/appleple/react-modal-video/blob/master/src/index.jsx#L26).
The package seen to not support a prop for closing Modal by keydown event of ESC. Maybe you can try to add an keydown event listener to over the package default event. But I am not sure it can work.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.keyCode === 27) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```